# On my bootstrap website the alertbox returns my whole web file

Tags: php

Basically, on  my website, I was trying to create a login system and I did it and everything's fine until my alert box from bootstrap4 started returning my web file after logging in - 
return of my web file from the alert box:
https://gyazo.com/aa21b2f0ae4d427348c0e35495de0c2e,
and the actual web file:
https://gyazo.com/29c4768bf0206feb667b9ab438f626bc

Sorry for not posting it in the image block but i needed to have at least 10 reputation points in order to do that and without them it will be hard to understand

I've tried undoing my actions but it still didn't help and the problem persists

I get 2 PHP notices:

```
PHP Notice:  session_start(): A session had already been started - ignoring in (path)/action.php on line 46, referer: https://website.com/index.php
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in (path)/session.php on line 6, referer: https://website.com/index.php
```

And the code that it refers to:
Action.php

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'login') {
   session_start(); // line 46 in action.php

   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
```

Session.php

```
session_start();
require 'includes/config.php';

$user = $_SESSION['username']; // line 6 in session.php
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT username, activetill FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
$stmt->execute();
```

And the actual code that makes the alert box return something:

```
$("#login").click(function(e) {
    if (document.getElementById('login-form').checkValidity()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'action.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: $("#login-form").serialize() + '&action=login',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response === "You\'ve been successfully logged in.") {
                    window.location = 'panel.php';
                } else {
                    $("#alert").show();
                    $("#result").html(response);
                    $("#loader").hide();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: If you show us ALL of `action.php` then maybe we can point you at the problem. That issue is all about what has happened above line 46

Comment: The undefined index! Well where did you set a value into `$_SESSION['username'];` because the error is saying that you didnt create that array occurance yet

Comment: @RiggsFolly well above the line 46 didnt happen really much expect the registration function which i dont think you'd care about so i'll just show you what happened above the registration function:   ` require 'includes/config.php';`
`require 'includes/pbkdf2.php';`
`require 'session.php';`